# Youtube: Display upcoming Live events on web page

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-plus, google-hangouts

I have a Youtube Live Events account and I'm using Google Hangouts in Google Plus to create Upcoming Live Events. Is it possible at all to somehow relay this upcoming events list to my webpage? My webpage uses PHP 4.3.8 (I know it is a bit outdated...).

I just want the user to create the events and given what they create on Google Hangouts have my page query and show a list and link of these.

Answer (score 1):

You can list your live events using the [YouTube LiveStreaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/).

Here's a sample PHP code for this.

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/list_broadcasts.php

Comment: I tried it, but I guess because my version of PHP is so old, I get a few errors.

Comment: You also need Google API PHP client library. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: Sadly, they only support PHP 5.2 and above. I am on 4.3.8.

Comment: I realize that this thread is nearly 10 years old, but the link you shared was a godsend for me.  Thank you